# Clone a project to a specific folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is it possible that in my ruby on rails project I can implement a function that automatically clones a project from a repository in a specific folder ?, would there be a way to do it ?, is it possible?

I would like to know if ruby on rails has any way of doing it or if there is a gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the official git gem https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git

```
Git.clone(URI, NAME, :path => '/tmp/checkout')
```